# X-editable helloworld

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, x-editable

I am trying to workout a HelloWorld example of Bootstrap3 and X-editable. I am attaching my page source code in this post. I am facing two issues.

1. I am getting the following error when i use mode as 'popup' as soon as i click on the editable link.
   TypeError: this.getCalculatedOffset is not a function
2. If i switch from popup to inline at-least the page appears however, the buttons dont appear correctly.

[image]

Any feedback would be appreciated. Page Source is below:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>X-Editable Bootstrap Hello World!</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="twitter-bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css"/>
      <link href="bootstrap-editable/bootstrap3-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css" rel="stylesheet">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container">
         <h1><a href="#">Hello World Bootstrap</a></h1>         
         <div class="hero-unit">
            <p>Hey.. this is my very first XEdit-able Bootstrap site.</p>
            <!-- <a href="#" id="username" data-type="text" data-placement="right" data-title="Enter username">superuser</a> -->
            <a href="#" id="username">superuser</a>
         </div>
      </div>

      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <script src="twitter-bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>  
      <script src="bootstrap-editable/bootstrap3-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.js"></script>     

        <script type="text/javascript">

            $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';

            $(document).ready( function(){

                //$('#username').editable();

                $('#username').editable( {
                    type: 'text',
                    pk: 1,
                    url: '/post',
                    title: 'Enter username'
                });

            } );

        </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your bootstrap css and js files must be from 2.xx version of bootstrap, that's a problem.
Use x-editable for bootstrap 2 or update your bootstrap to version 3+.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after upgrading from Bootstrap 2 to Bootstrap 3.
I had upgraded Bootstrap's CSS, X-Editable's CSS and JS, but had forgotten to upgrade Bootstrap's JS which was still for v2.

Don't forget to update all files:

- Bootstrap 3 `.css` and `.js`
- X-Editable for Bootstrap 3 `.css` and `.js`

Probably a bit late, but hopefully that can still help someone.